# как обращаться к html form по имени в django

Tags: python-3.x, html5, django, django-orm

Мне нужно взять описание элемента базы данных и отрендерить его в шаблон. Для этого я сделал форму и в её название впихнул id, чтобы затем обратиться к ней, взять id и обратиться к элементу в БД и взять описание нужного мне элемента(описание -- одно из полей таблицы БД), но я не знаю как мне во views.py обратиться к форме по имени и как обратиться к элементу БД по id. 
мой код:
cat_of_plants.html:

```
{% extends 'main_page/main_page.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="container-content">
    {% for pl in plant %}
      <div class="container-content-block">
        <div class="text">{{ pl.latin_name }}</div>
        <div class="image">
          <img src="/{{ pl.image.url }}/" alt="картинка не работает" width="170" height="200">
        </div>
        <div class="text">{{ pl.price }} руб</div>
        <div class="text">{{ pl.name }}</div>
        <form class="server" action="" name="plants_basket_{{ pl.id }}">
          <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="В корзину">
        </form>
        <form class="server" action="info/" name="plants_info_{{ pl.id }}">
          <input class="btn btn-light" type="submit" value="Подробнее">
        </form>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

class plants(models.Model):
    latin_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique = True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', db_index = True)
    price = models.IntegerField(db_index = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique = True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=10000, default='something')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import PlantsForm
from .models import plants, shrimp, snag, snail
# Create your views here.
def cat_of_plants(request):
    Plants = plants.objects.all()
    return render(request,'content/cat_of_plants.html',context = {'plant': Plants})
```

content/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('cat_of_plants/', cat_of_plants),
    path('cat_of_shrimp/', cat_of_shrimp),
    path('cat_of_snails/', cat_of_snails),
    path('cat_of_snags/', cat_of_snags),
]
```

main/urls.py (в директории с settings.py):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', hello),
    path('content/', include('content.urls'))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Мне нужно взять описание элемента базы данных и отрендерить его в шаблон

Форма нужна для манипуляции с данных из БП, а не для вывода.

Для вывода - передаете в контескт объект или набор объектов (тот же queryset) и выводите в шаблоне как `{{ object.field_name }}`

---

UPDATE:

> но мне нужно взять из шаблона id элемента, на котором нажали на кнопку. Как мне это сделать?

```
{# Если надо получить в JS #}
<button data-id="{{ object.pk }}" onclick="alert(this.dataset.id)">
{{ object.field_name }}
</button>

{# Если надо получить в Django на другой странице #}
<a href="{% url view_name pk=object.pk %}">Тык меня</a>

{# Или через параметры #}
<a href="{% url view_name %}?id={{ object.pk }}">Или меня</a>
```

Comment: но мне нужно взять из шаблона id элемента, на котором нажали на кнопку. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: после второго варианта пишет Invalid block tag on line 18: 'views.py', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?  я что-то не так сделал или что? PS я написал так: <a href="{% views.py cat_of_plants id=pl.id %}">Тык меня</a>

Comment: почитайте для начала документацию по шаблонам и шаблонным тегам, а также углам в django. ваше `{% views.py cat_of_plants id=pl.id%}` даже близко не стоит с валидным кодом.

Comment: а еще лучше пройтите туториал

Comment: покажите ваш urls.py

Comment: я добавил в вопрос 2 файла с url

Comment: добавьте view и url для отображения 1 объекта, ссылаясь по pk, и используйте 1 вариант для передачи id через django в ссылке

Comment: не совсем понял вашу мысль

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Разобрался сам в языке шаблонов джанги и понял, как это делать. простите, что так тупил.